# MyApp.exe.config is not being loaded in Winforms application

Tags: c#, winforms, app-config

I am using ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key] to read configuration from MyApp.exe.config. It was all working fine until yesterday. I have tried rebuild clean project, copy output always, readded reference using System.Configuration.
couple of new configurations added yesterday are missing when tested on developer machine. Seems like its picking up old configs.

In real environment it works fine. just developer machine i cannot spot the difference. I understand there is MyApp.exe.config gets cached. I would like to find out where is it? What is the best way to tackle this issue?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: It does not get cached.  Random guess is that you added settings with Scope = User and they are now getting loaded from a different user.config file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. <appSettings>

    
    <add key="settingname"/></appSettings> this is what i am using. Reason i said about cached is when i remove MyApp.exe.config the application still reads configurations.

Comment: Have you modified the machine.config file on your dev system (usually located somewhere like C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config, depending on .NET version/architecture)? If you have anything in the <appSettings/> element there then it'll get inherited by every single .NET app you run.